# c++ and mongodb - can't compile - undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost

I am trying to use mongodb for the first time in c++.  I just installed the latest version on Ubuntu and also installed the lastest v2.0 c++ driver code.  It compiled just fine using scons.  In the c++ file the below is my include.

```
#include <client/dbclient.h>
```

So..I am assuming I have to make a ref to a boost library but I don't know how to do it.

```
make all 
Building target: rtb
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/include/ -L/home/boost -L/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0/mongo -lfcgi++ -o"rtb"  ./src/rtb.o   
./src/rtb.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rtb] Error 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468280/1971003

Answer (score 4):

Add `-lboost_system` to your link line.

Comment: g++ -L/usr/local/include/ -L/home/boost -L/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0/mongo -lfcgi++ -lboost_system -o"rtb"  ./src/rtb.o   I still get the same error

Comment: Well that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me...perhaps try running `objdump -x` against your copy of libboost_system and seeing if the symbols you are missing are indeed in there.  Next, try running `strace` on your `make` link step to see if it is indeed opening the same file you objdump'd.

Comment: Try putting ./src/rtb.o before -lboost_system.