# C++ Boost: undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()

Tags: c++, linux, boost, codeblocks

I am trying to include `Boost` libraries in my project and have been facing issues in the same. I am on Ubuntu 12.10 with Codeblocks IDE and tried installing the libraries manually reading instructions from the site, but was getting error's with header as well as to-be-built-before-use libraries.

I then installed the libraries via terminalby `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`. After this, in my programs on Codeblocks, I can include headers like `#include <boost/regex.hpp>` but when I try to include the header for the Filesystem library ( `#include "boost/filesystem/operations.hpp"`  ), I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|214|undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()'|
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error (specifically in Codeblocks on Linux). I really could use some help here.

Compiler : Gcc
Program code: Only tried inlcuding the above file system `operations.hpp` file.

Build log from Codeblocks:

```
Build started on: 20-11-2012 at 18:02.53
Build ended on: 20-11-2012 at 18:02.54
-------------- Build: Debug in libopenFrameworks ---------------
Target is up to date.
-------------- Build: Debug in reader1 ---------------
make -s -f Makefile Debug
linking i686 bin/reader1_debug linux
obj/i686Debug/src/testApp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
obj/i686Debug/src/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/reader1_debug] Error 1
Process terminated with status 2 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
6 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: your not linking it right, codeblocks won't do it for you unlike you system path and system repository,

Comment: @pyCthon: In that case, can you add more detail more detail about how to link this in Code::blocks. I tried adding the linker flag `-lboost_system` at some place in settings, but it didn't resolve. However, I am not even sure if I did the whole linker flag thing at the right place. A little more detail would be of great help.

Comment: well what compiler are you using? mingw? gcc? what code are you trying to run? give an example.....

Comment: @pyCthon: Comiler is Gcc. I have not written any code till now, but have tried including the `Boost filesystem library` (operation.hpp in the above post)

Comment: does it work compiling a regular program with boost filesystem library from command line with g++?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You should link in the `libboost_system` library. I am not sure about codeblocks, but the g++ command-line option on your platform would be

> -lboost_system

Comment: I already found the linker flag to be added though. Can't get it working in Codeblocks.

Comment: @Cipher can you obtain the build and link commands executed by codeblocks?

Comment: @Cipher sorry, pastebin is blocked at work. I can check later but it will take a few hours.

Comment: No problem. Updated in the post as well

Comment: i have the same problem as Cipher's, just in my case i deal with boost/asio.hpp. I get these error http://s1.directupload.net/images/130608/koyvqpdp.jpg when trying to compiler. When i try to add -lboost_system it says "cannot find lboost_system". What;s the problem?

Comment: @ddacot are the boost libs in your library search path?

Comment: @juanchopanza i'm not quiet sure what are you talking about, but i have these lines in my .pro file 
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/boost_1_53_0/
LIBS += "-LC:/boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/" -lboost_system

Comment: @ddacot OK, you seem to be on some windows system, probably using mingw, right? I am not familiar with the exact options you need for that.

Comment: @juanchopanza some days ago i compiled boost for vs2012 and it works fine. Now i need to use in qt but can't. Yeap, i'm on w8. Yes Qt creator uses Mingw as default compiler.

Comment: In cmake this will be include_directories(${libfoo_INCLUDE_DIRS}) and then target_link_library(MyLib ${libfoo_LDFLAGS}).

Comment: if you are using CMake the following lines should be added:

add_library(boost_system STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(boost_system PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53.a")

add_library(boost_filesystem STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(boost_filesystem PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.a")

Answer (score 22):

Depending on the boost version libboost-system comes with the -mt suffix which should indicate the libraries multithreading capability.

So if `-lboost_system` cannot be found by the linker try `-lboost_system-mt`.

Comment: It works because for these boost versions the actual library file name had a `-mt` suffix.

Answer (score 11):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50146757/2028846) actually helped when using Boost and cmake.

Adding `add_definitions(-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)` for cmake file.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(proj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


set(SHARED_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../shared")

set(BOOST_LATEST_DIR            "${SHARED_DIR}/boost_1_68_0")
set(BOOST_LATEST_BIN_DIR        "${BOOST_LATEST_DIR}/stage/lib")
set(BOOST_LATEST_INCLUDE_DIR    "${BOOST_LATEST_DIR}/boost")
set(BOOST_SYSTEM                "${BOOST_LATEST_BIN_DIR}/libboost_system.so")
set(BOOST_FS                    "${BOOST_LATEST_BIN_DIR}/libboost_filesystem.so")
set(BOOST_THREAD                "${BOOST_LATEST_BIN_DIR}/libboost_thread.so")

set(HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_DIR           "${SHARED_DIR}/hyrise_sql_parser")
set(HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_BIN_DIR       "${HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_DIR}")
set(HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_INCLUDE_DIR   "${HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_DIR}/src")
set(HYRISE_SQLPARSER                "${HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_BIN_DIR}/libsqlparser.so")


include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${BOOST_LATEST_INCLUDE_DIR} ${HYRISE_SQL_PARSER_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)

find_package(Boost 1.68.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread filesystem)

add_executable(proj main.cpp row/row.cpp row/row.h table/table.cpp table/table.h page/page.cpp page/page.h
        processor/processor.cpp processor/processor.h engine_instance.cpp engine_instance.h utils.h
        meta_command.h terminal/terminal.cpp terminal/terminal.h)


if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(proj PUBLIC Boost::system Boost::filesystem Boost::thread ${HYRISE_SQLPARSER})
endif()
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a linker problem. Include the static library path into your project.

For Qt Creator open the project file `.pro` and add the following line:

```
LIBS += -L<path for boost libraries in the system> -lboost_system
```

In my case Ubuntu x86_64:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system
```

For Codeblocks, open up `Settings->Compiler...->Linker` settings tab and add:

```
boost_system
```

to the Link libraries text widget and press <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

Answer (score 8):

I searched for a solution as well, and none of the answers I encountered solved the error, Until I found the answer of "ViRuSTriNiTy" to this thread: [Undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200300/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category)

according to that answer, try to add these lines to your cmake file:

```
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)
include_directories(... ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(... ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(... ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 5):

Same problem on building a simple boost example, solved after i changed the g++ compiler flag from **-std=c++14** to **-std=c++11**.

And I noticed that it's a C++11 Example...

Comment: That solved my issue. It's quite easy to forget the flags used during compilation, specially when you use the default ones.

Comment: You just saved my life. I encountered this problem in a legacy C++11 codebase, the Boost linking error doesn't make any sense and I've wasted several hours on this problem. Your post finally made me realize that the "undefined reference" was caused by a C++ ABI conflict, as the operating system's Boost was built in C++17. Rebuilding a local version of Boost from source using `./b2 cxxflags=-std=c++11` and now it works like a charm!

Comment: On further inspection, `--std=c++11` only cured the symptom, not the root cause. The actual problem occurred because the source tree was built using bundled Boost headers from an old version, but at link time, it was linked against a much newer Boost from the operating system creating ABI conflicts. This is clearly not guaranteed to work. Using `--std=c++11` with a different Boost version may or may not work, if it does, it's still a coincidence. The real solution is to simply replace the bundled Boost to the new version, or to build the same old Boost from source and link against it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and also use Linux Mint (as nuduoz) . I my case problem was solved after i added `boost_system` to `GCC C++ Linker->Libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

You could come across another problem. After installing Boost on the Linux Mint I've had the same problem. Linking `-lboost_system` or `-lboost_system-mt` haven't worked because library have had name `libboost_system.so.1.54.0`.

So the solution is to create symbolic link to the original file. In my case

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 /usr/lib/libboost_system.so
```

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16710047/3195752) question.

Answer (score 1):

> g++ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem userentry.cpp -o userentry

worked perfectly under debian. (boost c++ libraries installed with apt-get).

Answer (score 1):

Il the library is not installed you should give boost libraries folder:

example:

> g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem prog.cpp -o prog

Answer (score 0):

try

```
g++ -c main.cpp && g++ main.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so && ./a.out
```

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is the location of the boost library

use `find /usr/ -name '*boost*.so'` to find the boost library location

Answer (score 0):

After testing the proposed solutions described above, I found only these few of lines would work.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)  
project(myProject)  

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)  
add_executable(myProject main.cpp)  

find_package(Boost 1.58.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)  
target_link_libraries(myProject ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project I prefer to use header-only libraries. So nothing above was helpful. What did really help is:

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED)
```