# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "boost::system::generic_category

Tags: xcode, boost, c++11

I already know there are many ask about this ERROR here, All of them , [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467072/c-boost-undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category) suggest me add **-lboost_system** flag to solve it, but it doesn't work.

Here is my step:
I'm a iOS programmer and I'm already using Boost.System/Boost.FileSystem in my project. Recently, I need to upgrade my project to C++11, including Boost. So I use `"brew install boost --with-c++11"` to install my Boost:C++11. Then it stops in compiling:

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from ...`

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:...`

Following StackOverFlow, I add **-lboost_system** in my Xcode project, which is in `Other C Flags` and `Other C++ Flags` in Build Setting.

But, the error does not changed.

Comment: I know little about Apple/XCode environments but the error message `for architecture armv7` certainly looks like you installed boost for your host platform, not for your target platform. Just a wild guess.

Comment: If so, there will be much more error rather than 2.

Comment: It should be in linker flags.