# G++ cannot find boost library

Tags: c++, boost, g++, linker-errors, ld

I am not good in command-line compiling. My problem is inability to compile simple project, that depends from Boost. The following is a log of my trying:

```
$ g++ -Wall test.cpp -o main
/tmp/ccCTvBYE.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccCTvBYE.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[_ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467072/c-boost-undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category) I found instructions for adding`-lboost_system` or `-lboost_system-mt`. I got the following:

```
$ g++ -lboost_system -Wall test.cpp -o main                                                                                                                    
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ g++ -lboost_system-mt -Wall test.cpp -o main                                                                                                                 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to locate `boost_system` library.

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep boost_system
    libboost_system.so.1.53.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.53.0
```

Then I unsuccessfully tried the following

```
$ g++ -I"/home/third_party/boost/" -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" -lboost_system -Wall test.cpp -o main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now I am stuck. How to form the command to compile?

***Edit:***

The following trying didn't help, too.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.53.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
ldconfig -n /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep boost_system
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       51 янв.  21 19:47 libboost_system.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.53.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    14536 окт.  13 07:14 libboost_system.so.1.53.0

$ g++ -I"/home/third_party/boost/" -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" -lboost_system -Wall -m64 boost_async.cpp -o main
/tmp/ccE20K2W.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccE20K2W.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[_ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @Jmc - Thank you. Unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Are you using `bjam`?

Comment: Sorry.. my ideas were no good.
I was thinking maybe it's the version numbers after the library name.
You could try creating a link to libboost_system.so that links to libboost_system.so.1.53.0 in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ directory

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Boost built with the earlier on this computer. And it available from compiling other projects with `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I wrote, that I've tried `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep boost_system`. Do you mean this `ldconfig` call?

Comment: Can you try adding `-m64` to the build? It's a reach... but your build looks correct.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Unfortunately, `-m64` didn't help

Comment: Can you try linking the lib to exclude the version number? Try `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.53.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so` and try it again with the same include path.

Comment: @Robin After that, remember to run `ldconfig` again!

Comment: @Robin, ElliottFrisch - Thank you. However, didn't help. (I expand the questions with this try

Comment: Try placing the link directives at the end of command line after the ```-o main``` part.

Comment: @amcn - I'm novice. what is _link_ _directives_?

Comment: The link directive is the `-lMYLIB`

Comment: I don´t an linux env to verify, but try `g++ -I"/home/third_party/boost/" -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"  -Wall test.cpp -o main -lboost_system`(note the `-lboost_system` at the end).

Comment: @Loom - I meant put the -lboost_system at the end of the command. Apologies if my wording was unhelpful. Wesley and Colin explained it better than I did.

Comment: @Loom - Sure thing. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you place the linker directive `-lboost_system` at the end of the command line like so:

`g++ -I"/home/third_party/boost/" -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" -Wall -m64 boost_async.cpp -o main -lboost_system`

this should solve the problem. Thanks to [Colin D Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994153/colin-d-bennett) and [wesley.mesquita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890548/wesley-mesquita) for clarifying this answer.