# Simple Boost code doesn't build

Tags: c++, windows, boost, codeblocks

When I am including the asio header:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

I got the error:

```
undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()
```

So I read that I had to link to `boost_system` which I did. But now it gives the error::

```
cannot find -lboost_system
```

Why can it not find `boost_system`. I'm using Codeblocks on Windows.

Comment: Where does it look for boost_system?

Comment: @zmbq I set the library path to "C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0\libs"

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Boost: undefined reference to boost::system::generic\_category()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467072/c-boost-undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category)

Comment: @l'L'l The answer there says to link to `-lboost_system`. But that's what's giving me this error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

boost is a separate library that needs to be installed on you building machine. 
Please follow these instructions to install:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html
http://www.boost.org/
After installation your application needs to be able to find it if it is not installed in a standard location.

you will need to supply the header and lib directories to the build process.

```
g++ source source.cpp -I/path to boost headers -L path to boost libs -lboost_system
```

Look inside you libs directory to be sure that you have boost_system.  It is possible depending on the build that you may only have boost_system-mt

Comment: Weird. When I look inside "C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0\libs" I can't find anything called `boost_system`. It's just a bunch of other folders.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  It appears that you only downloaded and did not bootstrap and install.

Comment: What should `PREFIX` be when installing Boost.Build? Can it be anything I want or does it need to be somewhere specific?

Comment: It can really be anywhere.  But try to keep it in a location accessible for development.

Comment: Will I have to make a folder to put it in or will it create a folder itself (it won't flood the directory with files)?

Comment: I installed boost build and I have a `bin` and `share` directory in the `PREFIX` directory that I specified. What do I do now??