# g++ not finding boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I am trying to compile a program using CGAL and linked to Boost. When I run the linker:

```
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/name/Qt/5.4/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/name/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib -o meld main.o mainwindow.o test.o moc_mainwindow.o   -lCGAL -lgmp -lmpfr -lboost_system -L/home/name/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

and get the error

```
main.o: In function `global constructors keyed to main.cpp':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

What am I doing wrong? I saw a couple of answers to similar questions but none seem to work for me.

Comment: Could be the order you're linking stuff in, try moving `-lboost_system` to the end of the library list. Or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5651869/241631)

Comment: What is the full path to `libboost_system.so` ?

Comment: @donjuedo /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so` tell you?  This is an area I really don't know, so please don't shoot me.  :-)  But I noticed your Qt libs seems to be 64 bit.  I am wondering if the linker won't use 32 bit for a 64 bit build.  It would make sense to have some sort of provision for backward compatibility.

Comment: @donjuedo Thanks, I appreciate the help (no intention on shooting you ;)! I get `symbolic link to libboost_system.so.1.58.0` and then running `file` on that linked file I get `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`

Comment: I'd try Praetorian's suggestion -- I have seen that work before.  If it still does not, I'd try forcing the search with another -L option, for your full path to the right library.  I know, you should not need that, but it is a mystery.

Comment: Oh!  I noticed pthread.  This old SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467072/c-boost-undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category mentions using the boost_system-mt library instead.  It's worth a shot.