# How to find Boost libraries with cmake and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I compiled Boost 1.65.1 with Visual Studio 2017.

When compiling some C++ project using cmake the Boost libraries are not found:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" -DBoost_COMPILER="-vc150" ..

CMake Error at cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1900 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: C:/Boost/include/boost-1_65_1

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_system
          boost_regex
          boost_timer
          boost_filesystem
          boost_serialization

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

the libraries are there:

```
dir c:\Boost\lib
 Volume in drive C has no label.

 Directory of c:\Boost\lib

28/11/2017  12:47    <DIR>          .
28/11/2017  12:47    <DIR>          ..
...
28/11/2017  12:12           937.796 libboost_filesystem-vc150-mt-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:40         6.792.370 libboost_filesystem-vc150-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:20           996.592 libboost_filesystem-vc150-mt-s-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:17         5.951.092 libboost_filesystem-vc150-mt-sgd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:28           996.456 libboost_filesystem-vc150-s-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:25         5.950.956 libboost_filesystem-vc150-sgd-1_65_1.lib
...
28/11/2017  12:13        13.418.950 libboost_regex-vc150-mt-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:40        43.663.182 libboost_regex-vc150-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:21        13.487.852 libboost_regex-vc150-mt-s-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:17        42.108.148 libboost_regex-vc150-mt-sgd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:28        13.487.546 libboost_regex-vc150-s-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:25        42.107.842 libboost_regex-vc150-sgd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:16         9.426.284 libboost_serialization-vc150-mt-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:43        33.389.696 libboost_serialization-vc150-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:24        10.690.636 libboost_serialization-vc150-mt-s-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:20        34.091.376 libboost_serialization-vc150-mt-sgd-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:31        10.690.106 libboost_serialization-vc150-s-1_65_1.lib
28/11/2017  12:27        34.090.846 libboost_serialization-vc150-sgd-1_65_1.lib
...
             200 File(s)  2.184.720.662 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  48.071.262.208 bytes free
```

How to use Boost in this configuration?

EDIT:

I see that there is a naming problem. From FindBoost.cmake:

```
#   Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED  - Set to OFF to use the non-multithreaded
#                              libraries ('mt' tag).  Default is ON.
#   Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS    - Set to ON to force the use of the static
#                              libraries.  Default is OFF.
#   Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME - Set to ON or OFF to specify whether to use
#                              libraries linked statically to the C++ runtime
#                              ('s' tag).  Default is platform dependent.
#   Boost_USE_DEBUG_RUNTIME  - Set to ON or OFF to specify whether to use
#                              libraries linked to the MS debug C++ runtime
#                              ('g' tag).  Default is ON.
#   Boost_USE_DEBUG_PYTHON   - Set to ON to use libraries compiled with a
#                              debug Python build ('y' tag). Default is OFF.
#   Boost_USE_STLPORT        - Set to ON to use libraries compiled with
#                              STLPort ('p' tag).  Default is OFF.
#   Boost_USE_STLPORT_DEPRECATED_NATIVE_IOSTREAMS
#                            - Set to ON to use libraries compiled with
#                              STLPort deprecated "native iostreams"
#                              ('n' tag).  Default is OFF.
#   Boost_COMPILER           - Set to the compiler-specific library suffix
#                              (e.g. "-gcc43").  Default is auto-computed
#                              for the C++ compiler in use.  A list may be
#                              used if multiple compatible suffixes should
#                              be tested for, in decreasing order of
#                              preference.
#   Boost_THREADAPI          - Suffix for "thread" component library name,
#                              such as "pthread" or "win32".  Names with
#                              and without this suffix will both be tried.
#   Boost_NAMESPACE          - Alternate namespace used to build boost with
#                              e.g. if set to "myboost", will search for
#                              myboost_thread instead of boost_thread.
```

there is no mention of 'gd' or 'sgd' tag, but my libs are named like that.
I tried also to disable all options that could use those tags, but it is still failing:

```
 cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" -DBoost_COMPILER="-vc150" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/c/Boost/lib -DBoost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF -DBoost_USE_DEBUG_RUNTIME=OFF ..

CMake Error at cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1900 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: C:/Boost/include/boost-1_65_1

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_system
          boost_regex
          boost_timer
          boost_filesystem
          boost_serialization

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

Comment: The bundled cmake can find the pre-built windows binaries from boost here: https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.65.1/binaries/. The main difference is that the libraries are organized by architecture and compiler version, so the paths look like: C:\local\boost_1_65_1\lib32-msvc-14.1, and C:\local\boost_1_65_1\lib64-msvc-14.1. Maybe it is only looking for the libs in those folders?

Answer (score 3):

**About the library naming:**

Boost library (.lib,.dll on Win, .a,.so on Linux) names have 3 forms. They depend on the `--layout` option which was passed to `b2` when boost was built. On Windows the default is `versioned`, which produces the file names you had.
[See my detailed explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208574/5951077)

**Possible solutions to your problem:**

1. In your 2nd try you called
   `cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" -DBoost_COMPILER="-vc150" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/c/Boost/lib ...`
   However I'm not sure the path `/c/Boost/lib` is valid for Windows CMake, please try `C:\Boost\lib`.
   BTW, instead of `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` I would define simply `BOOST_ROOT=C:\Boost`.
2. Since you have only libs and NOT DLLs, make sure that `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is `ON` in your CMake file (or passed on the command line).
   If you happen to use python and/or numpy libraries, too, then you need to define `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` and `BOOST_NUMPY_STATIC_LIB`, as well, for the compiler, when you include headers from these libs (e.g: `add_definitions(-DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -DBOOST_NUMPY_STATIC_LIB)`).
3. Turn on boost diagnostics:
   `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`
   CMake file print lot of info about how it tries to process boost.

Note:
Normally you don't need to set the `Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED`, etc. variables, since these are detected by CMake. From your "lib" directory file list, I can see that both debug and release, dynamically and statically linked C run-time versions of the library files were present.
[See here about these letters in the library file names.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming)

I hope some of these helped.